# DBCC CHECKIDENT Reseed start from -2147483648

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with `ID` as a primary key. `ID` is `int` datatype which is auto increment identity start from `-2147483648`.

I just delete all the records, then I am trying to make it start from the beginning. I want to start the first record with `-2147483648`.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, -2147483648)
```

If I run the script above, it will start from `-2147483647`. Then I tried the following script:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, -2147483649)
```

The error said:

> Parameter 3 is incorrect for this DBCC statement

How can I start the identity from `-2147483648`?

Thank you.

Comment: try truncating the table instead of delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

Truncate will Reset your Identity values.
Delete will not Reset your Identity values..

I think Try to Change Your Data type **Integer into Bigint**

```
 drop table ck
create table ck(id bigint identity(-2147483649,-1)not null,name varchar(20))

insert into ck values('AA');
insert into ck values('bb');
insert into ck values('cc');

select * from ck;

delete from ck
truncate table ck

DBCC CHECKIDENT('ck', RESEED, -2147483649)
```

Comment: Yes, Truncate is the best way to do this. Cheers mate,